# Using javascript, how to select an li relative to a specific other li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Given the following html list:

```
<ul>
   ...
   <li>
   <li>    // <-- item to be selected
   <li>
   <li class='current'>
   <li>
   <li>
   <li>
   ...
</ul>
```

How do I select the li two instances ahead of the li with class current?
Any pure javascript or jquery solution would be great!

Comment: If you know how to select the previous element, you're half way there. If you don't, then you need to run through some tutorials and documentation.

Comment: edit: removed comment, added to question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making it more generic, i.e if you want to select a li possibly(2nd or 3rd or what ever instance that appears prior to your selector), then try

```
$('li.current').prevAll(':eq('  + n-1 + ')');
```

Here n would be the instance # that you are talking about (Since it is 0 based index). In your case this would be:

```
$('li.current').prevAll(':eq(1)');
```

*Do remember that prevAll returns the elements in the order starting from the selector, so you can just provide the index of the element from that position in `prevAll` with `eq` selector.*

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sLsbr/)**

Comment: I have accepted this answer. Others were correct, but I prefer the generic nature of this solution!

Comment: @ArnolddeJager You are welcome. That was my point as well in the answer, in case you want to select element at a diff index then a generic always helps!!

Answer (score 2):

Very easily:

```
$('.current').prev().prev()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
$('.current').prev().prev()
```

Answer (score 2):

This may help...

```
var li=document.getElementsByTagName('li');
var i, n;
for(i=0;i<li.length;i++)
{
    if(li[i].className=='current')
    {
        n=(i+2)%(li.length);
    }
}
var x=li[n];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have accepted an answer. My own solution first identified the index of the element to be selected:

```
var index = $('.current').index()-n+1;
```

n equals the number of items you want to be ahead of the current object. The +1 is because indexing starts at zero, yet nth-child at 1.

I then used the nth-child selector to get the right element:

```
$('ul li:nth-child('+index+')')
```